# sql query group/sum and turn rows into combined columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to turn the source table into a summation table on a few factors.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

date and id will be the rows.
exprev and type will be combined to create a column
amount will be summed

I tried pivot table but I couldn't figure out a way to combine columns, ie. 'rent expense'
[image: sample data and result]

UPDATE
conditional aggregation works but I forgot to add one more scenario.
I need to add a column for the currency of the item, then change the result to have a local amount, and a converted amount to USD.

new screenshot below
[image: updated source and result image]

update...
I added to the select and the group by.
,case when a.exprev = 'Expense' and a.type= 'rent' then a.Currency else 'nothing' end as [rent Currency]
now I am getting an extra row of inaccurate data in my result.
it has created 2 lines of data for each id when it should be only 1 line of data

Comment: Do you know exactly which columns you need before looking at the data, or is there potentially combinations of exprev and type you won't know about in advance?

Comment: I ask because the SQL language has a very strict rule: it MUST know about ALL the columns in the results at query compile time, before looking at ANY table data. If you don't know this, you will NOT be able to pivot the data in a single query. Instead, you'll need three steps: `1)` Run a query to find out what your columns are. `2)` Build a new dynamic query based on results from 1. `3)` Run the query from 2.

Comment: for argument sake... lets say I will know the exact columns

Comment: Do you want to get the result showing in your screen shot? If so I can give you a hint using postgresql database

Comment: yes, I am looking to get the result from the screenshot I attached

Comment: Use case when clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for argument sake... lets say I will know the exact columns

In that case you would use **conditional aggregation**, like this:

```
SELECT [date], id
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'expense' and type='rent'      then amount else 0 end) [rent expense]
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'revenue' and type='rent'      then amount else 0 end) [rent revenue]
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'expense' and type='tax'       then amount else 0 end) [tax expense]
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'revenue' and type='tax'       then amount else 0 end) [tax revenue]
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'expense' and type='insurance' then amount else 0 end) [insurance expense]
    ,SUM(case when exprev = 'revenue' and type='insurance' then amount else 0 end) [insurance revenue]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [date], id
```

Comment: thank you... this works but I forgot to add one more scenario to this.  I am adding to the original question now

Comment: basically in my result, I need to add the currency of the item, then provide columns for local and usd amounts.  I tried simple adding a select line but then it said other columns where not in the group by

Comment: With this addition you follow the same basic pattern, but you need to double the number of `,SUM(...)` lines, where each line now includes an additional conditional check for the currency.

Comment: the first issue I'm seeing is when I try and add the column for 'rent currency'. the result in my scenario is the string 'EUR'.  when I try to add it using ,case when a.exprev = 'Expense' and a.TranType = 'Exchange Fee' then a.Currency else 'nothing' end as [Exchange Currency], i get errors

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'a.ExpRev' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'a.TranType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'a.Currency' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Read the message again. It says what it means.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong.  I added the following line in my select and also group by.  now it is giving me an extra row of data.  I understand my logic is wrong just not sure how to fix it.  updating more info of what I tried above in original post.     case when a.exprev = 'Expense' and a.type= 'rent' then a.Currency else 'nothing' end as [rent Currency]